# MIgrate Android ADT Project Which have .SO(SQLite Cipher) +External Lib to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new for Android studio i have to migrate adt project which have external support project like volley +google maps and sql cipher .so file I am unable to migrate ADT to android studio i followed many tutorials for that but I am getting run time problem **Unable to load .so files/jniLib** (jniLibs>>arembi-v7a) in studio

```
Please assist me.
```

Thanks in advance
  Ranjan.

Comment: on your ADT do you have a gradle build file or did you just add the libs in the  libs folder? also what are you doing exactly, how are you importing your project to AS and what options are you choosing??

Comment: No, I don't have gradle build file in ADT so, First i exported ADT project as gradle and import into AS after that i am getting lot of resource not found error like custom font(app:textfont="robot").

Comment: try this way. copy the whole project folder and paste it on your desktop and then open AS and choose (Import project Eclipse ADT, Gradle etc), choose the folder on the desktop. it should then ask you if it should create the gradle for you. say yes Give that a go. also i wouldn't have eclipse and AS on the same computer if you do. either the one or the other but not both together.